# Couchbase: How to flush memcached bucket with N1QL?

Tags: couchbase

I have a memcached bucket that I want to flush with a query.

```
DELETE FROM my_memcached_bucket;
```

Running the query above returns an error `This bucket type is not supported memcached`.

How can I clean everything from `my_memcached_bucket` inside of the query?

Comment: I don't think memcached buckets support N1QL - see: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/buckets.html - I believe you can use the REST API though - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-bucket-flush.html